# Is this the right way to free memory in C?

Tags: c

I have a struct in C as follows:

```
typedef struct ArrayStruct{
float * array;
size_t used;
size_t size;
}Array;
```

I initialize it as follows:

```
void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = (float *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(float));

    if(a->array){
    }
    else{
        printf("OUT OF MEMORY 1!!\n\r");
    }

    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}
```

My question is: Is the following code the right way to free up any memory being utilized by the struct :

```
void freeArray(Array *a) {
   a->array = NULL;    
   free(a->array);
   a->used = 0;
   a->size = 0;
}
```

Please help. Thank you. :)

Comment: Obviously, it is not.

Comment: Yeah. I thought so too. But If I do that, the program halts. :/

Comment: Then there is another problem which you don't show. Perhaps this needs the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're right. Maybe there is another problem. On a side note, and pardon me for my lack of knowledge, but what is the point of returning 'a' ?

Comment: Another detail: `if(a->array){` is an incomplete test given that `initialSize` could be 0, in which case a `NULL` return is _valid_.  Suggest `if(a->array && initialSize > 0) {`.  Other approaches exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not the right way of doing the `free`, because you set the pointer to be freed to `NULL` *before* actually freeing it. You should do it the other way around:

```
free(a->array);  // Free the memory
a->array = NULL; // Clear out a dangling pointer
```

The pattern with an empty conditional branch is questionable, too. Rather than doing

```
if(a->array){
}
else{
    printf("OUT OF MEMORY !!!\n\r");
}
```

you should do

```
if(!a->array){
    printf("OUT OF MEMORY !!!\n\r");
}
```

You should also set `a->size` to zero when the allocation fails (currently your code falls through to the case that sets size to `initialSize` even on a failed allocation):

```
if(!a->array){
    printf("OUT OF MEMORY !!!\n\r");
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = 0;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That `freeArray` uses the wrong order. It first sets `a->array` to `NULL`, then tries to `free` a `NULL` pointer. This doesn't work. You need to swap the first two lines in the function: first `free`, then set the pointer to `NULL`.

```
void freeArray(Array *a) {
   free(a->array);
   a->array = NULL;   
   a->used = 0;
   a->size = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
void freeArray(Array *a) {
   a->array = NULL;    
   free(a->array);
   a->used = 0;
   a->size = 0;
}
```

You are first assigning NULL to the pointer, let's see what happens when you call free with a NULL pointer looking some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

> void free( void* ptr ); Deallocates the space previously allocated by
>   malloc(), calloc(), aligned_alloc, (since C11) or realloc(). If ptr is
>   a null pointer, the function does nothing.

So nothing happens, you're not deallocating anything, you are creating a memory leak as you don't have the reference to the memory anymore.

To make it works you just need to change the order and set NULL after

```
void freeArray(Array *a) {
   free(a->array);
   a->array = NULL;    
   a->used = 0;
   a->size = 0;
}
```